# Using DirectShow AsyncReader with C#

Tags: c#, c++, directshow

I am running an `AsyncReader` to open a shared MPG file that is being downloaded by another application (progressive download). The shared MPG file is created with `FILE-SHARE-READ | FILE-SHARE-DELETE | FILE-SHARE-WRITE` shared permissions. I have even tried every combination of those flags.

Here's the problem: within C# the `AsyncReader.Load` method returns a error:

> file in use

Within C++ it does not. C++ opens the file just fine.

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why this is?

This is because [File Source (Async) Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375641) is opening file exclusively, without allowing others to progressively write to the file in the same time.

Code for same/similar asynchronous reader from old SDK, where it was available as a sample, contains:

```
// Open the requested file
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(lpszFileName,
                          GENERIC_READ,
                          FILE_SHARE_READ,
                          NULL,
                          OPEN_EXISTING,
                          0,
                          NULL);
```

Note `FILE_SHARE_READ`. Your options are:

1. Complete progressive download before opening for playback
2. Build a custom reader from SDK sample and change the file opening mode to allow writing as you play it